# Error while compiling with gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir

I am using both **Laravel Elixr** and **Laravel mix** as shown bellow and compiling **scss** files

> OS = Windows 10
>
> node -v = v6.11.0
>
> npm --v = 5.0.3

```
+-- laravel-elixir@6.0.0-15
| `-- gulp-sass@2.3.2
|   `-- node-sass@3.13.1
`-- laravel-mix@0.11.4
  `-- node-sass@4.5.2
```

and the error is Cannot find module 'cloneable-readable' as I show bellow

```
> [05:51:53] Using gulpfile D:\www\fevrok.com\gulpfile.js 
> [05:51:53] Starting 'all'...
> [05:51:53] Starting 'sass'...
> [05:51:54] 'sass' errored after 713 ms
> [05:51:54] Error: Cannot find module 'cloneable-readable'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\www\fevrok.com\node_modules\gulp-concat\node_modules\vinyl\index.js:8:17)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
> [05:51:54] 'all' errored after 745 ms
> [05:51:54] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(sass)'
> Message:
>     Cannot find module 'cloneable-readable'
> Details:
>     code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
> Stack:
> Error: Cannot find module 'cloneable-readable'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\www\fevrok.com\node_modules\gulp-concat\node_modules\vinyl\index.js:8:17)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the missing Modules like that

```
npm install cloneable-readable
npm install clone-buffer
```

in my case, it was those 2 above

Comment: It seems to work for me also. 
Did you find out why that module wasn't installed by gulp and maybe open an issue for them?

Comment: @Ben2307 it's been a while since that error shows up but I think it didn't install because it's defined as optional I will check then I will open an issue if not opened yet.